# Как оплатить GCP из России? Есть ли достойные аналоги для российских разработчиков?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud

Гугл закрыл платёжный аккаунт. Новый создавать не пробовал. Все русские карточки не принимают. И что теперь делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретнее

1. Принимает ли гугл Union Pay? Находил самую противоречивую информацию. Может, уже кто проверил?
2. Или же даже с разрешённой картой гугл не даст создать новый платёжный аккаунт? Где я укажу не Россию, естественно, в качестве моей страны. Адрес случайный укажу.
3. Есть ли русские аналоги? Самыми важными сервисами были IoT, Machine Learning, Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: А что случилось?

Comment: @S.H. 6000 тыщ человек которые друг друга игнорят)

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать оплатить через rubscribe. С ними можно заключить договор и официально оплачивать. Но будут комиссии. Сам искал аналоги, но стоящего ничего не нашел.